# Covert iff from v4 to Pinescript v5

Tags: type-conversion, pine-script-v5

I'm trying my best to understand how to convert code form v4 to v5 and I have some successful attempts on some easy scripts, but I don't have any code skills, I'm trying to learn by myself the thing I need, but and I miss the basic to understand well what I'm doing really.

So I'm asking you if you can help me with this, so I can learn from this too.
Thank you

```
///....

xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
xATRTrailingStop := iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss),
   iff(src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss), 
   iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src - nLoss, src + nLoss)))
 
pos = 0   
pos :=  iff(src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
   iff(src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 


///...
```

I tried to convert "iff" to a ternary operator, I'm sorry if that's a mess :/

```
xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
xATRTrailingStop := (src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]) ? math.max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss) :
   (src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss) :
   (src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src - nLoss, src + nLoss))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to v5 by clicking on the left of the pinescript editor :

[image]

The code of the v5 will be like this :

```
xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
iff_1 = src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? src - nLoss : src + nLoss
iff_2 = src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss) : iff_1
xATRTrailingStop := src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? math.max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss) : iff_2

pos = 0
iff_3 = src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)
pos := src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) ? 1 : iff_3
```